# Inherited Classes from Abstract Class field mysteriously overwritten

Tags: c#

My problem is once the program reaches MyMethod() once, it sets LocalField and InheritedProperty as the same one pointer, meaning whenever InheritedProperty changes LocalField does automatically too.

```
class Inherited : AbstractClass
{
    protected override void MyMethod()
    {
        LocalField = InheritedProperty;
    }

    public void MyNewMethod()
    {
        //Is the new Array different?
        //Do something
    }

    public long[] LocalField;

    protected override long[] InheritedProperty => RetrtieveNewArray;
}
```

Is it possible to someone make my LocalField a new field independent from InheritedProperty?

Comment: These are all references to the same thing. So if you change that thing, the changes will be reflected in all the _references_ to it

Comment: What do you want `LocalField` to be? A copy of `InteritedProperty`? I.e. initialized with the same elements, but not changing along with `InheritedProperty`? You could use `Array.Copy` for that purpose. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @maccettura sorry, just copied from my browser ... updated my comment

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on here when we only have bits of the code. Please provide a [mcve] - it'll be *much* easier to help you that way. (If you want to create a separate array, then `LocalField = InheritedProperty.Clone();` would probably be the simplest approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the array:

```
LocalField = (long[]) InheritedProperty.Clone();
```

This will create an independent copy of the original array.

In your case the array element type is a value type (`long`) which means that cloning will copy all the numbers. However, if you do the same with an array containing references you will only get a "shallow" copy meaning that the references in the cloned array will reference the same objects as the references in the original array. This is not something relevant to the code in your question but something that you should be aware of when cloning arrays in general.